# I am getting some syntax error in my PHP code, which i am unable to solve

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I am getting some syntax error in my PHP code, which I am unable to solve.
Please have a look at this and help me to solve this. [Here Is The Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmx6H.png).

I have attached the screenshot of the error which I am getting on line 14.

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','satyam');
    if(isset($_POST['name']))
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE name='".$name."'";
        $sql_run = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_run))
        {
            $name = $row["name"];
            $roll = $row["roll"];
            $branch = $row["branch"];
            $address = $row["address"];
            echo 'Name: '.$name.' Roll: '.$roll.' Branch: '.$branch.' Address: '.$address';
        } else {
            echo "No Record Found";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: you have a ' too many.

Comment: check this line `echo 'Name: '.$name.' Roll: '.$roll.' Branch: '.$branch.' Address: '.$address';` Might be time for you to start using a proper IDE.

Comment: remove extra quote from `'.$address';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added an extra unnecessary single quote (`'`) end of the following line

```
echo 'Name: ' . $name . ' Roll: ' . $roll . ' Branch: ' . $branch . ' Address: ' . $address;
```

This code works fine.

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','satyam');
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name    = $_POST['name'];
    $sql     = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE name='" . $name."'";
    $sql_run = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_run)) {
        $name    = $row["name"];
        $roll    = $row["roll"];
        $branch  = $row["branch"];
        $address = $row["address"];
        echo 'Name: ' . $name . ' Roll: ' . $roll . ' Branch: ' . $branch . ' Address: ' . $address;
    } else {
        echo "No Record Found";
    }
}
```

Comment: and you have pasted whole code just to answer that issue is with single quote ? This should be closed as it can not be reproduced

Comment: Thanks For Your Help. My Problem Has Been Solved now.

Comment: Just FYi, you could have just added the line you changed rather than copy the whole code ;)

Comment: I have added the errored line at first and pasted full code with formatted.

Comment: @SatyamKumar Glad to help you, dude. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `'` at the end of :

```
echo 'Name: '.$name.' Roll: '.$roll.' Branch: '.$branch.' Address: '.$address';
```

after `$address`

Answer (score 0):

Please check this :

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','satyam');
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE name='".$name."'";
    $sql_run = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_run))
    {
        $name = $row["name"];
        $roll = $row["roll"];
        $branch = $row["branch"];
        $address = $row["address"];
        echo 'Name: '.$name.' Roll: '.$roll.' Branch: '.$branch.' Address: '.$address;
    } else {
        echo "No Record Found";
    }
}
?>
```

You added a extra ' on this line :

```
echo 'Name: '.$name.' Roll: '.$roll.' Branch: '.$branch.' Address: '.$address;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
echo 'Name: '.$name.' Roll: '.$roll.' Branch: '.$branch.' Address: '.$address';
```

Should be:

```
echo 'Name: '.$name.' Roll: '.$roll.' Branch: '.$branch.' Address: '.$address;
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the quotation mark (') at the end of line 14 (the one next to the semicolon).